# Polymer sorting json data by descending order

Tags: json, sorting, polymer

I can't find any answer on how to sort data from my json-response from highest to lowest in Polymer. I am using iron-ajax to display the data in a table and that works, but it's not sorted.

I want to sort the "amount" in my json response so it displays in my table in a descending order.

The json looks like this

```
[
  {
    "orderid": 1,
    "name": "Apple",
    "amount": 100
  },
  {
    "orderid": 2,
    "name": "Banana",
    "amount": 730
  }
]
```

And so on.

Any idea how to do this in polymer?

Answer (score 1):

When `iron-ajax` return `last-response`, it's trigger `on-response` functions `sortList` that will sort the list.

```
<iron-ajax
    auto
    url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search"
    handle-as="json"
    last-response="{{items}}"
    on-response="sortList">
</iron-ajax>

        items: {
          type: Array,
          value: function () {
            return []
          }
        }

      sortList: function () {
        return this.items.sort(function (a, b) {
          return a.value - b.value;
        });
```